# How to reduce playback speed of PCM data?

Tags: android, audio, audio-streaming

Folks,

In my Android application, I record audio and play it back. The user is usually a singer.

I now need the ability to play the audio back at reduced speed.

As I understand, PCM data is simply a mix of sine waves at different frequencies. There is one dominant wave (highest magnitude) that results in the musical notes of the song.

To reduce the speed by 2 times, at first I thought I will just duplicate each sample. For example, if the sampled input PCM values are 20000, 25000, 30000, ..., I will play back 20000, 20000, 25000, 25000, 30000, 30000. However, this doesn't seem to be the right solution. All I seem to be doing here is increasing the wavelength (therefore frequency) of the sine waves. I think this will result in changing the voice/notes.

Can someone please suggest how to reduce or increase the speed?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

If by speed you mean varying the voice in the PCM data from slow (tall giant) to fast (chipmunk) then

you might want to look at this [algorithm for pitch shifting.](https://sites.google.com/site/mikescoderama/pitch-shifting). The idea is to get the right sampling rate as per the pitch that you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am not looking at changing the voice. I just want to play the recording at a reduced speed.